# Failed to resolve: com.google.android.gms:play-services:15.0.1 after adding ML Kit

Tags: android, firebase, google-maps, google-maps-api-3, firebase-mlkit

[Look here](https://i.stack.imgur.com/dzN92.png) Please I tried to add ML Kit to my app's build gradle but it didn't run completely. I guess it must be from my build.gradle file but I don't know where. Please help?

```
dependencies {
    implementation fileTree(dir: 'libs', include: ['*.jar'])
    implementation 'com.android.support:appcompat-v7:27.1.1'

    //Firebase libraries
    implementation 'com.google.firebase:firebase-auth:16.0.2'
    implementation 'com.google.firebase:firebase-database:16.0.1'
    implementation 'com.google.firebase:firebase-storage:16.0.1'
    implementation 'com.google.firebase:firebase-messaging:17.1.0'
    implementation 'com.google.firebase:firebase-core:16.0.1'
    implementation 'com.google.android.gms:play-services-ads:15.0.1'
    implementation 'com.google.firebase:firebase-ads:15.0.1'
    implementation 'com.google.firebase:firebase-ml-vision:16.0.0'

    //Other Stuff
    implementation 'com.firebase:geofire-android:2.3.0'
    implementation 'com.android.support:support-vector-drawable:27.1.1'
    implementation 'com.android.support:support-v4:27.1.1'
    implementation 'com.android.support:design:27.1.1'
    implementation 'com.android.support:cardview-v7:27.1.1'
    implementation 'com.android.support:recyclerview-v7:27.1.1'
    implementation 'com.android.support:support-v13:27.1.1'
    implementation 'com.r0adkll:slidableactivity:2.0.6'
    implementation 'de.hdodenhof:circleimageview:2.2.0'
    implementation 'com.google.android.gms:play-services-maps:15.0.1'
    implementation 'com.android.support:multidex:1.0.3'
    testImplementation 'junit:junit:4.12'
    androidTestImplementation 'com.android.support.test:runner:1.0.2'
    androidTestImplementation 'com.android.support.test.espresso:espresso-core:3.0.2'
    implementation 'com.android.support:support-annotations:27.1.1'
    implementation 'com.google.android.gms:play-services:15.0.1'
}
```

Below is the build.gradle(project). I have even included the google repository but still to no avail. Please help

```
    buildscript {

    repositories {
        google()
        jcenter()
    }
    dependencies {
        classpath 'com.android.tools.build:gradle:3.3.0-alpha03'

        classpath 'com.google.gms:google-services:4.0.2'
    }
}

allprojects {
    repositories {
        google()
        jcenter()
        maven{
            url 'https://maven.google.com'
        }
    }
}

task clean(type: Delete) {
    delete rootProject.buildDir
}
```

Comment: Try to change this `implementation 'com.google.android.gms:play-services:15.0.0'` by this `implementation 'com.google.android.gms:play-services:15.0.1'`

Comment: It still doesn't work please

Comment: What could be the problem please?

Comment: Relative librairy or I think your class path to google in the other gradle can you put it

Comment: I have it. I am updating my post

Comment: Can you put the main gradle file.

Comment: I have edited my post

Comment: Try to replace `classpath 'com.google.gms:google-services:4.0.2'` by `classpath 'com.google.gms:google-services:4.0.1'`

Comment: It still didn't work please

Comment: I find it remove `implementation 'com.google.android.gms:play-services:15.0.1'`

Comment: And if don't is because you need to add `apply plugin: 'com.google.gms.google-services'` at the end of you first gradle file.

Comment: I have it @crammeur. It's still not working

Comment: What is the error the same or other

Comment: same error. Still "failed to resolve blah blah"

Comment: I thing this can help us https://firebase.google.com/docs/android/setup

Comment: Do you have the last android studio version

Comment: yes i am using the latest version

Answer (score 2, accepted):

The [Google API Release Notes](https://developers.google.com/android/guides/releases#april_12_2018_version_1500) indicate that support for the combined `play-services` library ended in April 2018:

> Starting with 15.0.0, there will no longer be a play-services alias
>   target to pull in all Google Play services components. This has been
>   recommended against for some time.

You can no longer specify a dependency on the combined Google Play services target, `implementation 'com.google.android.gms:play-services:15.0.1'`. When this was supported with previous versions, it pulled in ALL the Google Play libs--way more than you need. See the list of APIs in Table 1 of the [Setup Guide](https://developers.google.com/android/guides/setup#add_google_play_services_to_your_project) and include only the specific ones your app uses.

A check of the [Google Maven Repository](https://mvnrepository.com/artifact/com.google.android.gms/play-services) confirms that version 12.0.1 was the last version of the combined play-services` target.

Comment: I tried changing to 12.0.1 and it worked for some reason. But now I get new error. It says     error: cannot access zzbgl
class file for com.google.android.gms.internal.zzbgl not found

Comment: How do I fix this?

Comment: Don't use `play-services:.x.x.x`.  As I explained in the answer, replace it with the specific APIs your app uses.

Answer (score 0):

Hopefully this line fixes it overwrites a version check that was built in recently
`com.google.gms.googleservices.GoogleServicesPlugin.config.disableVersionCheck = true`

```
dependencies {
    implementation fileTree(include: ['*.jar'], dir: 'libs')
    implementation 'com.android.support:appcompat-v7:27.0.0'


   //Google API dependencies -JACOB 
    implementation(project(":react-native-google-signin")){         
        exclude group: "com.google.android.gms" // very important excludes undeeded packages so specific ones can be grabbed
    }
    implementation "com.google.android.gms:play-services-base:15.0.1"  // should be at least 15.0.0 to work with most recent APIS
    implementation "com.google.android.gms:play-services-auth:15.0.1"
    implementation "com.google.android.gms:play-services-identity:15.0.1"
    implementation ('com.google.android.gms:play-services-vision:12.0.1') {
        force = true
    }

    //React native camera 
    implementation (project(':react-native-camera')) {
    exclude group: "com.google.android.gms"
    implementation 'com.android.support:exifinterface:25.+'
    implementation ('com.google.android.gms:play-services-vision:12.0.1') {
        force = true
    }
}
    // Firebase dependencies -JACOB
    implementation project(':react-native-firebase')
    implementation "com.google.firebase:firebase-core:16.0.1"
    implementation "com.google.firebase:firebase-firestore:17.0.2"
    implementation "com.google.firebase:firebase-database:16.0.1"
    implementation "com.google.firebase:firebase-auth:16.0.2"

    //React Native Elements Vector Icons
    implementation project(':react-native-vector-icons')

    implementation project(':react-native-fbsdk')
    implementation "com.facebook.react:react-native:+" 
    // From node_modules
}

// Run this once to be able to run the application with BUCK
// puts all compile dependencies into folder libs for BUCK to use
task copyDownloadableDepsToLibs(type: Copy) {
    from configurations.compile
    into 'libs'

}

apply from: "../../node_modules/react-native-vector-icons/fonts.gradle"
apply plugin: 'com.google.gms.google-services'
//NEEDED TO RUN GOOGLE SIGN IN DUE TO DEPRACATED API IN GOOGLE DEPENDENCIES THAT CONFLICTS WITH NEW VERSIONS OF GRADLE -JACOB
com.google.gms.googleservices.GoogleServicesPlugin.config.disableVersionCheck = true
```

Comment: This doesn't make sense. Of course I have done all this.

Comment: ahahaha, fair point. My bad that is me misreading the issue, I will see what I can figure out, sorry about that.

Comment: Do you have apply plugin: 'com.google.gms.google-services' in the build.gradle (app) ?

Comment: Yes I do. I just didn't add it

Comment: try this at the very bottom of that same build.gradle `com.google.gms.googleservices.GoogleServicesPlugin.config.disableVersionCheck = true`

Comment: As or plugin or as an implementation?

Comment: as written, it would go below everything. here I will show mine.

Comment: hmmm, interesting. Did you add everything for that ML kit in the MainApplication?

Comment: Every single detail. The issue is with my build.gradle. Nowhere else

Comment: try changing the classpath to `classpath 'com.android.tools.build:gradle:3.1.3'`

Comment: Dang. Those were some good possible leads too. Let me look some more, however, I am currently dealing with a build error myself so it may take some time to get back to this.

Comment: Bob Snyder's answer helped. Thanks for your input though.